# Reactjs lifecycle methods for state management bug

Tags: reactjs

i have this code

```
    fetchUserData(){
        if(this.props.user){
            console.log(this.props.user.displayName);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.user){
            this.fetchUserData();
          }
      }
    
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(this.props.user && this.props.user !== prevProps.user){
            this.fetchUserData();
          }
      }
```

I expect it to print the displayName of the user only when the user is not null, but when i check my console, it first prints null, and only after that the correct name. What am I missing?

Comment: why are all methods async?

Comment: Sorry about that, i copied the template from another component where the fetch functions called firebase @RameshReddy

Comment: perhaps, `this.props.user` is not null but `this.props.user.displayName` is null

Answer (score 1):

why do you have to do this, it's not doing anything other than console.log, and actual data coming from props.

```
    fetchUserData(){
        if(this.props.user){
            console.log(this.props.user.displayName);
        }
    }
```

let handle things at the parent level.

and one more thing I observed, you are comparing two objects it's not gonna work.

```
 this.props.user !== prevProps.user
```

may be you can try in parent component like

```
  return (
    // some parent code
    {this.state.user ? <User  user={this.state.user}/>: <PlaceHolder/>}
    // some parent code
   )
```

[Note]: it may not be the answer, but you got idea right?